# how to remove sliding closet doors with wheels on both sides

Tags: doors, closet

I need to get my closet doors off so that I can replace appliances. There are tracks on either side so I can't lift it. I also don't see any latch. Anyone know how to take this kind of door off the track? [image]

Comment: Nice picture! Can you get us one from the other face of the door (move around to your right)? My instinct would be to unscrew the nut on there, but putting it back on will require readjusting the doors for level, which would be fiddly. There may also not be enough clearance to lower the door. Could you remove the whole track from the ceiling with the doors still attached?

Comment: What does it look like from the left?  Can you unscrew the bracket that the wheels are attached to?

Comment: Either remove the bottom nuts, or remove the whole track.  Unless the doors can roll off at the ends of the tracks, which I doubt with door frames.  The theaded bolt might have two flats for fitting a wrench to hold.

Answer (score 3):

See that nut above the bracket in the door? Get a thin wrench (they do make them specifically for pocket doors, but you might have to fake it). Loosen the nut a little. Slide the assembly sideways off the bracket on the door. (One side of the bracket is almost certainly open.)

And yes, it’s way more fiddly than it sounds in the paragraph above.